# Is there a Definitive C# Book Guide/List question?

Tags: discussion

I noticed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) regarding the Definitive C++ Book Guide and List, and I was wondering if a similar question exists for C#. I am asking because I couldn't find one.

Thanks

Comment: These book questions are not on-topic for SO. Likewise, the majority of them have been purged (historically locked or deleted). The C++ one remains because it's the only one that's well maintained.

Comment: First google hit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5795/recommended-books-for-learning-c

Comment: @UphillLuge I had found that already, but the C++ question was really detailed + well maintained, and was wondering if a C# question in the same vein had posted before the rules were changed.

Comment: *"I had found that already"* -- [Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask)... Thanks!

Comment: There's nothing that didn't meet my needs. I was impressed with the effort the C++ guys had put into maintaining a quality book list, and was curious to know if there was a similar question but for C#.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope. Such questions used to be on topic, but they aren't any longer. Please see [Q&A is Hard, Let's Go Shopping!](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) and [The Future of Community Wiki](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/) for more details on this.

Since a C# question wasn't asked during the period when it was on topic, there probably won't be one. You can ask in the [C# chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7/c) for some suggestions, though.

Comment: I found a whole bunch of small C# book questions. But not a single canonical big one.

Answer (score 4):

There isn't a question about C# books, but you will find a list of books when you look at the tag wiki for [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23).

Questions about books are not considered on-topic for Stack Overflow, but tag wikis can list books as part of a list of useful resources.

Comment: [Link to tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%23/info).